# How to rewrite postgresql procedure to avoid second call

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to rewrite this plpgsql procedure to avoid **json.get_user_notifications** being called twice?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json.rowset_notifications(arg1 integer, arg2 integer, arg3 integer)
  RETURNS SETOF json.notification AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  pmax_limit boolean;
BEGIN
  pmax_limit := (SELECT COUNT(*) > 200 FROM json.get_user_notifications($1, $2, $3));
  IF pmax_limit THEN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT n.* FROM json.get_compressed_user_notifications($1, $2, $3) n;
  ELSE
    RETURN QUERY SELECT n.* FROM json.get_user_notifications($1, $2, $3) n;
  END IF;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE
  COST 100
  ROWS 200;
```

Something like that (of course it's not working):

```
WITH
    notifications AS (SELECT n.* FROM json.get_user_notifications($1, $2, $3) n LIMIT 201)
SELECT CASE
    WHEN COUNT(*) > 200 THEN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT n.* FROM json.get_compressed_user_notifications($1, $2, $3) n;
    ELSE
        RETURN QUERY SELECT n.* FROM notifications n;
    END
FROM notifications;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you look for that:

```
WITH notifications AS (
     SELECT n.*
       FROM json.get_user_notifications($1, $2, $3) n
      LIMIT 201
)
SELECT *
  FROM notifications
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) <= 200 FROM notifications)
 UNION
SELECT *
  FROM json.get_compressed_user_notifications($1, $2, $3)
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) > 200 FROM notifications)
```

;

Answer (score 0):

Sure, run the other query like this

```
SELECT n.*
FROM json.get_user_notifications($1, $2, $3) AS n
WHERE ( SELECT count(*)>200 FROM json.get_user_notifications )
```

You may have to be explicit. If that returns, then you can return the result set of `json.notification`. If it doesn't return then you know you need to return the compressed result set.

Comment: It seems that this example doesn't work:
    SELECT id
    FROM generate_series(1, 300) id
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(*) <= 200

Comment: @Fr1ar seems to work for me, you're trying to see if the `count(*) <= 200`. In your query, generate_series is generating `[1,300]` none of the values generate in that range are generate twice. They're all generated once, so the `count(*)` for all of them after the grouping is one..

Comment: OK, I got it. Unfortunately I forgot to mention that in my case all records are unique. I just need to know if count is greater than 200 then I return compressed set.

Comment: @Fr1ar try that.

Comment: SELECT n.* FROM generate_series(1, 300) AS n WHERE (SELECT count(*) <= 200 FROM generate_series)

Comment: It says: ERROR:  relation "generate_series" does not exist

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing. No idea at all. Or what you're even trying do.